# Override Angular default date names

Tags: angular, date-pipe

The names of months in pt-br LOCALE_ID put a dot when use format MMM, example: "Janeiro" to "jan."
How to replace the table of default names?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to overwrite this format, but if no one gives you a better solution, you always can do your own pipe to 'delete' the *dot*.

In your pipe, you only have to map the 12 month with dot to antoher 12 without dot ( 'jan.' => 'jan'), using **String replace()* to change them.

How to create your own pipe:
*https://www.angularjswiki.com/pipes/custompipe/*

How to replace a string for another (for instance, 'jan.' to 'jan'):
*https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_string_replace.htm*